# Adding a group to a crossfilter with more than 82 records runs out of memory

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

I'm using crossfilter to drive some charts with `dc.js` but I'm getting out of memory crashes when working with more the 82 records.

My records are an array of objects like this:

```
{
  "date": Thu May 24 2018 11:29:27 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time),
  "recipients": ["name1", "name2"],
  "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
}
```

and I'm performing the initial load of data like this:

```
var ndx = crossfilter(items)
this.displayItems = ndx.allFiltered()
var dateDimension = ndx.dimension(d => d.date)
var dayHourDimension = ndx.dimension(d => [d.date.getDay(), d.date.getHours()])

// by day
var detailGroup = dateDimension.group(d => {
  if (d) { // Chrome identifies this line as causing the out of memory crash
    return new Date(d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth(), d.getUTCDate())
  }
})
// by month
var overviewGroup = dateDimension.group(d => {
  if (d) {
    return new Date(d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth())
  }
})

var heatMapGroup = dayHourDimension.group().reduceSum(d => 1)
```

I've marked the point in my code where Chrome breaks before the crash occurs, and looking through the call stack, it's at [this point](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/blob/2ddc0e441d37172ad33cc94d18a3d640eebf0436/src/crossfilter.js#L848) in the crossfilter source where new values are added to the group (n.b. I'm using v1.4.5). The same crash occurs with more than 82 records in Edge and Firefox. I've tried cutting down the data in my records to just the dates but that makes no difference. Obviously I'd like to be able to handle far more than 82 records so does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Can you share the error message and/or the data? I’m guessing the 83rd record has an empty date field that results in your date dimension not being well ordered so you are getting a stack overflow error.

Comment: Hmm, good thought, I'll have a look. There isn't an error message per se, Chrome just identifies that executing the line will cause the memory error and halts executing the script.

Comment: That’s very odd. I’d like to see the problem if you can provide recreation instructions.

Comment: Ah, you were right, it's the data! I've filtered out the erroneous data and it's all fine.

Comment: Cool. The way we usually deal with this is by making sure that the dimension access never returns a null/undefined value. This is admittedly a bit tough for dates and numbers as you have to come up with a "blank" date and that's not always realistic.

Comment: Makes sense, I hadn't fully appreciated that. Thanks for the explanation, time to add a lot of `!isNaN()` to my code...

Comment: Yeah, the Crossfilter docs make clear that dimension accessors must return well-ordered values, but we haven't been successful in making clear just how important that is.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an accepted answer for this. OP themselves managed to pinpoint the error in the comments to the question.

The solution here was to make sure that crossfilter gets **100% perfect data**. No empty lines in a CSV, no blank properties in a JavaScript object, nothing like that.